# RequireJS - Applying Constructors To Modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, state-machine

I've got a module which houses a creation method of sorts. The module is loaded in to another module via requireJS like so:

```
define(['lib/state-machine'],
    function (stateMachine) {

        // Creator method.
        stateMachine.create({
            events : [  { name: 'Enter', from: 'Initialised', to: 'Running' }],
        });
    }
);
```

By default the creator method takes in an object full of callbacks. What I would like it to be able to do is use the module calling it as it's object for callbacks. So for example if I used the standard approach and gave the creator an object like this:

```
callbacks { onEnter: function () { 
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

It should actually go to 'onEnter' in the module itself:

```
define(['lib/state-machine'],
    function (stateMachine) {
        function onEnter () {
           // This method gets fired by the state machine.
        }

        // Creator method.
        stateMachine.create({
            events : [  { name: 'Enter', from: 'Initialised', to: 'Running' }],
        });
    }
);
```

Note: The state machine assumes the existence of a method based on an event name. So when the Enter event fires it always tries to find an onEnter method. The state machine I'm using can be found at: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make like the code example in the Readme file?

```
function (stateMachine) {
    function onEnter(event, from, to) { /* your code goes here */ }

    // Creator method.
    stateMachine.create({
        events : [  { name: 'Enter', from: 'Initialised', to: 'Running' }],
        callbacks: {
            onEnter: onEnter
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yep I did see this. What I am trying to do though is not have to specify callbacks at all, so it instinctively calls onEnter on my module.